# Keras fit vs. fit_generator extra smaples

Tags: keras

I have training data and validation data stacked up in two tensors. At first, I ran a NN using [`keras.model.fit()`](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit) function. for my purposes, I wish to move to [`keras.model.fit_generator()`](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator). I build a generator and I have noticed the number of samples is not a multiplication of the batch size.

My implementation to overcome this:

```
indices = np.arange(len(dataset))# generate indices of len(dataset)
num_of_steps = int(np.ceil(len(dataset)/batch_size)) #number of steps per epoch
extra = num_of_steps *batch_size-len(dataset)#find the size of extra samples needed to complete the next multiplication of batch_size
additional = np.random.randint(len(dataset),size = extra )#complete with random samples 
indices = np.append(indices ,additional )
```

After randomizing the indices at each epoch I simply iterate this in batches skips and pool the correct data and labels.

I am observing a degradation in the performance of the model. When training with `fit()` I get 0.99 training accuracy and 0.93 validation accuracy while with `fit_generator()` I am getting 0.95 and 0.9 respectively. note, this is consistent and not a single experiment. I thought it might be due to `fit()` handling the extra samples required differently. Is my implementation reasonable? how does `fit()` handles datasets of a size different from a `batch_size` multiplication?

Sharing the full generator code:

```
    def generator(self,batch_size,train):
        """
        Generates batches of samples
        :return: 
        """
        while 1:
            nb_of_steps=0
            if(train):    
                nb_of_steps = self._num_of_steps_train
                indices = np.arange(len(self._x_train))
                additional = np.random.randint(len(self._x_train), size=self._num_of_steps_train*batch_size-len(self._x_train))
            else:
                nb_of_steps = self._num_of_steps_test
                indices = np.arange(len(self._x_test))
                additional = np.random.randint(len(self._x_test), size=self._num_of_steps_test*batch_size-len(self._x_test))

            indices = np.append(indices,additional)
            np.random.shuffle(indices)
#            print(indices.shape)
#            print(nb_of_steps)

            for i in range(nb_of_steps):
                batch_indices=indices[i:i+batch_size]
                if(train):
                    feat = self._x_train[batch_indices]
                    label = self._y_train[batch_indices]
                else:
                    feat = self._x_test[batch_indices]
                    label = self._y_test[batch_indices]
                feat = np.expand_dims(feat,axis=1)
#                print(feat.shape)
#                print(label.shape)

                yield feat, label
```

Comment: When you say degradation do you mean in terms of speed? This makes sense as reading and writing from disk is the slowest operation you can do. 
Can you also share your generator code? it will make it easier to understand where the issue is!

Comment: @nickthefreak see my edit. Sharing the generator code in a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can simplify the generator significantly!
The number of steps etc can be set outside the loop as they do not really change. Moreover, it looks like the `batch_indices` is not going through the entire dataset. Finally, if your data fits in memory you might not need a generator at all, but will leave this to your judgement.

```
def generator(self, batch_size, train):
    nb_of_steps = 0
    if (train):
        nb_of_steps = self._num_of_steps_train
        indices = np.arange(len(self._x_train)) #len of entire dataset
    else:
        nb_of_steps = self._num_of_steps_test
        indices = np.arange(len(self._x_test))
    while 1:
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
        for i in range(nb_of_steps):
            start_idx = i*batch_size
            end_idx = min(i*batch_size+batch_size, len(indices))
            batch_indices=indices[start_idx : end_idx]
            if(train):
                feat = self._x_train[batch_indices]
                label = self._y_train[batch_indices]
            else:
                feat = self._x_test[batch_indices]
                label = self._y_test[batch_indices]
            feat = np.expand_dims(feat,axis=1)
            yield feat, label
```

For a more robust generator consider creating a class for your set using the `keras.utils.Sequence` [class](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence). It will add a few extra lines of code, but it is certainly working with keras.

Comment: This implementation is very helpful in terms of computation time. Thanks a lot. I am, however, asking on performance of the network as a classifier and not the computation time. Can you help with that as well?

Comment: I think the performance of the classifier is because the generator was not going through the entire dataset (so your `fit_generator` trained on a sub-set of the data. Unfortunately, it is hard to test the theory without the actual dataset. The different start/end indices should fix this problem, but let me know if not:
`start_idx = i*batch_size`
`end_idx = min(i*batch_size+batch_size, len(indices))`
`batch_indices=indices[start_idx : end_idx]`

Comment: This did improve the performance. So, if I am reading your implementation correctly, you simply gave a shorter last batch?

Comment: shorter last batch indeed, but also the batch indices now increase properly; the look previously was not going through the full length of the dataset.  Specifically, when looping through the steps, if `i=0` then your `batch_indices = 0 : batch_size`, when `i=1` ,`batch_indices = 1:1+batch_size`. By changing start and end index, your `batch_indices ` moves without overlapping elements on each loop